# Can I deploy package with msdeploy outside of Web Site default physical path?

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

IIS out of the box got Default Web Site with Physical Path "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot"

I am building Web Deploy package with Visual Studio. And I am able to deploy it using **.deploy.cmd** to whatever application name I specify in **.SetParameters.xml** file:

```
<setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site\MyApp" />
```

But physical path of that application is always inside of Default Web Site physical path. And application folder matches application name - MyApp.

After deployment I can move application into any folder and adjust App's Physical Path.

Is there any way to deploy application into folder other than default in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the "Use IIS settings" feature and it will use the path from your local IIS configuration when creating the package locally.

[How can I set the deployment path for an iisApp Provider using MsDeploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155632/how-can-i-set-the-deployment-path-for-an-iisapp-provider-using-msdeploy)